# Minimum pumping length of finite language

Tags: regular-languages, automata, pumping-lemma

**Background**
Let L = {aa}. We know that the minimum pumping length of L is |aa| + 1 = 3. For this length all the three conditions of the pumping lemma vacuously hold true.

**Doubt**
Let L = {aa, aab}. Is it right to say the minimum pumping length is max(|w| | w belongs to L) + 1(in this case |aab| + 1 = 4) for finite languages?

Comment: Try proving your assertion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pumping lemma for simple finite regular languages](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1847/pumping-lemma-for-simple-finite-regular-languages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $w \in L$ be the longest string of the finite language $L$. Assume a pumping length $p \leq |w|$. This would imply $w = xyz$ with $|y| \geq 1$ and $xy^2z \in L$. Can you see the contradiction?

Having ruled out pumping length $p \leq |w|$, the minimal possible value for $p$ is indeed $|w|+1$, for which as you noted the conditions of the pumping lemma are trivially true.